# How to install Nvidia drivers for RHEL8

Tags: rhel, drivers, nvidia, x-server

I am trying to install the Nvidia drivers for my graphics cards on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8. I open the terminal and change my directory to `Downloads` and type `su` then `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.59.run` but keep getting an error. I tried `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.59.run --no-x-check` and I was able to install the driver but when the computer restarted I continued to get a failed login screen. How do I disable X server

```
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
         installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING   
         THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver         
         download page at www.nvidia.com.


ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
         '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find            
         suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available   
         on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to install NVIDIA drivers directly from their website **only** if you're a power user and you exactly understand all the intricacies of the process. In Linux the preferred installation method is via repositories for your distro. Here's a manual which works for RHEL/CentOS/Fedora. Please follow it:

- Start with enabling RPM Fusion: https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/

Or simply run:

```
sudo rpm -ivh https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm
```

- Then proceed to install drivers: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA

Or simply run:

```
sudo dnf update -y
sudo dnf install kmod-nvidia
```

Changes will take effect after a full reboot on the newest kernel.

Comment: I went through the RPM Fusion and Howto/NVIDIA and that solved my problem, thank you.